# Updating values in nested variables

Tags: bash, variables

I want to create a variable from multiple variables by concatenating their values. After that I want to update value in those nested child variables and see the change in the parent one. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=123
b=abc

c=$a$b
echo $c # outputs 123abc

a=456
echo $c # outputs 123abc although I want 456abc
```

I'd like this to output `123abc` and `456abc` but instead I get `123abc` and `123abc`. Is it possible to achieve the behaviour I want in bash?

Comment: By doing `c=$a$b`, you're not assigning references of `a` and `b` to `c`, but you're assigning their values.

Comment: I suggest using a function instead of variable for nested variables like `c() { echo "$a$b"; }` and use it as `$(c)` in your script and you will get updated values all the time.

Answer (score 3):

In BASH (4+) you can create reference of variables using `declare -n` so if you have:

```
a=123
```

And create a **variable reference** as:

```
declare -n c=a
```

then `echo $c` will print `123`.

If you now change to `a=789` then if you execute `echo $c` again you will get updated value of `789`.

However this `reference` can be created for a single variable (or array) only, nor for combination of multiple variables.

As a simple *work around* consider using shell function for your usecase as this:

```
c() { echo "$a$b"; }
```

Then `$(c)` will always be dynamic and would always get you update value by concatenating values `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. Be careful though as **eval** use can be dangerous if you don't trust the input.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=123
b=abc

c="\${a}\${b}"
eval "echo $c"

a=456
eval "echo $c"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wasn't `eval` discouraged?

Comment: Yes. It is. As I pointed out. But its the *best* way to accomplish what OP wants

Comment: In an XY problem, the best way to solve Y is not necessarily a good way to solve X.